# How to get Active Window Control to show settings/menu bar?

Tags: kde, 19.04, plasma

I am having trouble finding the setting on how to allow the file menu to show up within Active Window Control when a window is set to full screen.

I already have `BorderlessMaximizedWindows=true` in my KDE config file now I am trying to get the file menu to show up in the top panel instead of the current open window. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Do you want the "global menu"? If so, these links may help: https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/plasma-global-menu-app-title-window-buttons-like-mac-unity.html, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425168/kde-global-menu-disappeared-in-plasma-5-12, etc.